# Approximating rational values in $]0,1[$ by a sum or difference of unit fractions

Tags: approximation-theory, diophantine-approximation

Let $U=\{\frac{1}{n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\} \cup \{-\frac{1}{n}: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ be the set of positive and negative unit fractions.

Are there positive integers $m<n \in \mathbb{N}$, such that for every $u,v\in U$ there are $u',v'\in U$ such that $|\frac{m}{n} - (u'+v')| < |\frac{m}{n} - (u+v)|$?

Comment: As it's now, for $\ u=v=1\ $ the difference is always the smallest (for any real, not just for positive rational numbers). You're possibly thinking about the absolute value of each side of the inequality. But the sums of elements of $U$ form a discrete set. Thus the answer is still NO (again for arbitrary reals).

Comment: This is not what one means by "approximation theory".  So I added "diophantine-approximation" ... maybe that's what this is?

Comment: Something very strange is written. Looks like a misprint.

Comment: That's correct - I put the absolute value signs in the wrong place and edited the post now accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose the intended inequality is
$$
\left| \frac{m}{n} - |u+v| \, \right| < \left| \frac{m}{n} - |u'+v'| \, \right|
$$
as **Wlodzimierz Holsztynski** suggests.  But
there are no such $m,n$.  Indeed for any real $r>0$,
rational or not, there exists a unique element of
$$
U + U := \{ u_1 + u_2 \mid u_1,u_2 \in U \}
$$
closest to $r$.

*Proof*: If $r\in U$ then $r \in U+U$, because
$r = \frac1n = \frac1{2n} + \frac1{2n}$.
If not, choose $n$ such that
$|r| \geq 1/n$.  Then if $u_1,u_2 \in U$ with
$|r - (u_1+u_2)| < \left|r - \frac1n\right|$ then at least one of $u_1,u_2$
exceeds $\frac1{2n}$; without loss of generality assume it is $u_1$.
Then there are finitely many candidates for $u_1$, and for each of them
there is an optimal choice of $u_2$ (because $r \neq u_1$ by hypothesis).
The optimal approximation is then the best one of these as $u_1$ varies over
the finite list of fractions larger than $1/2n$.

Comment: Sorry - I really got my $|\cdot|$ signs wrong. What I intended is the inequality $|\frac{m}{n} - (u'+v')| < |\frac{m}{n} - (u+v)|$. The goal is to approximate $\frac{m}{n}$ as good as it gets by a sum or difference of unit fractions, so I want to minimize $|\frac{m}{n} - (u+v)|$ where $u,v\in U$.